# Floating tag description caused by finishing an edit

Tags: bug, tags, review-queues, help-improvement

On a recurring but irregular basis, while reviewing in the Help and Improvement queue, I get a "floating" tag description in the upper left corner of my screen.

This happens after finishing an edit of a larger post that required scrolling down to reach the button to save. It is AFAIK triggered by scrolling that is a result of the collapsing edit window and the explicit scrolling to the top of the page that is a result of this edit finishing action: it causes the line with tags to  move from top to bottom underneath my cursor.

By the time my browser (Firefox) tries to display the pop-up for the tag the tag itself has scrolled out of view and the tag box shows up in the upper left corner. Clicking will make it go away.

As it is kind of distracting, can the tag pop-ups be disabled if the system scrolls the page and I am not hovering over the tag on purpose?